# Adding user to com security group using commandline or Powershell

Tags: powershell, com, command-prompt

I would like to do the follwoing

"Start | Run | dcomcnfg. This bring up the Component Services application. On the left pane navigate to Component Services | Computer | MyComputer. Right click on MyComputer and select properties. Select the COM Security tab and select the Edit Default button under Access Permissions. Use the Add... button to add the "Network Service" account to the permission list. Verify that ONLY the Local Access box is checked and click OK. Close out of Component Services. A reboot is then required to make the requested changes to COM Security.
"

Is there a way to do this via Powershell or through command line ?

Comment: Found an easier answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363342/change-dcom-config-security-settings-using-powershell

Answer (score 2):

I have done this for launch activation permissions and it isn't exactly straight forward.  I wrote up what I did in this [blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/using-powershell-to-modify-dcom-launch-activation-settings/).  I think it could get you pointed in the right direction.