# Can I dockerize Activex exe which has GUI?

Tags: docker, activex-exe

I am now working on a Dockerization of a legacy system which has ActiveX-exe, I didn't start on the dockerization yet, but while I am studying the application and its behavior using lisdlls in sysinternals, I found this line

C:\Program File\MyApplication\ActiveX-Exe.exe embedding

Does that mean it starts a full version of my exe, because if that happens it means that I cannot dockerize this application as this exe has GUI.

Comment: I worked on the dockerization and after I registered the COM Component, I got this error  " 80080005 server execution failed (exception from hresult: 0x80080005 (co_e_server_exec_failure)). " 

I tried this 
[solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363342/change-dcom-config-security-settings-using-powershell)
with no luck