# How configure a new DCOM RunAs User with Powershell

Tags: powershell, dcom

I know how to read my current DCOM configuration:

```
$dcom = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting -Filter 'Description="MyComp123"'
```

It works fine.
**But how can I create and assign a new RunAs (Identity) user?**

[image: identity option]

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363342/change-dcom-config-security-settings-using-powershell

Comment: I knowing about:
-SetLaunchSecurityDescriptor 
-SetAccessSecurityDescriptor 
-SetConfigurationSecurityDescriptor 
but I am looking for to edit the RunAsUser Identity option with PowerShell?
Have a look to my screenshot.

Comment: It seems like there is no programatic way - you have to use external executable as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/555745/change-a-dcom-applications-identity-with-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

See the two answers of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363342/change-dcom-config-security-settings-using-powershell). I think you can change the identity either via the `AccessSecurityDescriptor` or the `LaunchSecurityDescriptor`.

The identity can be changed via the registry:

`# We set to value to empty -> in this case the DCOM entries identitiy is set to "Launching User"
Set-ItemProperty -path ("Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{0}" -f $talDComEntry.AppID) -name "RunAs" -Value ""`

Comment: But you can not edit the identity user with the descriptors. (see screenshot)

Comment: I`ve updated the answer. As far as I can remember you can change the identity via a registry entry.

Comment: Thank you. But how to insert a new username with  right password?

Comment: You have to rely on external executable for this part as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/555745/change-a-dcom-applications-identity-with-a-script)