# Alternative to using DcomPerm.exe and SetAcl.exe in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script and trying to reduce the number of dependencies it has on external files. At the moment, I am making calls to DComPerm.exe and SetAcl.exe in the following manner:

**DComPerm.exe**

```
$newGroup = "JFSLJSDFJ\Mst-SvcAccounts"
$daListResult = .\DComPerm.exe -da list
$dlListResult = .\DComPerm.exe -dl list
.\DComPerm.exe -da set $newGroup permit level:r,l
```

**SetACL.exe**

```
$registryPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\34242342435435"
.\SetACL.exe -on $registryPath -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr "n:$machineHost\Administrators"
.\SetACL.exe -on $registryPath -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:$machineHost\Administrators;p:full"
```

Is it possible to replace these calls with Powershell code instead to reduce the dependencies on the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$newGroup = "JFSLJSDFJ\Mst-SvcAccounts"
$daListResult = .\DComPerm.exe -da list
$dlListResult = .\DComPerm.exe -dl list

& ".\DComPerm.exe -da set $newGroup permit level:r,l"
```

OR

```
Invoke-Expression "& `".\DComPerm.exe -da set $newGroup permit level:r,l`""
```

OR

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(".\DComPerm.exe -da set $newGroup permit level:r,l")
```

You can incorporate the same for the ACL also. You need some escape sequence while passing the parameters.

You can create an instance of **Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting**:

```
$dcomperm=Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting
```

DCOM application instances have several security descriptors. Starting with Windows Vista, use methods of the Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting class to get or change the various security descriptors. Security descriptors are returned as instances of the Win32_SecurityDescriptor class.

here is code I got from here for DCOM settings:

Reference Link : [DCOM Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363342/change-dcom-config-security-settings-using-powershell)

```
$user = "sql2012agent"
$domain = "MYDOMAIN"
$appdesc = "Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0"
$app = get-wmiobject -query ('SELECT * FROM Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting WHERE Description = "' + $appdesc + '"') -enableallprivileges
#$appid = "{83B33982-693D-4824-B42E-7196AE61BB05}"
#$app = get-wmiobject -query ('SELECT * FROM Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting WHERE AppId = "' + $appid + '"') -enableallprivileges
$sdRes = $app.GetLaunchSecurityDescriptor()
$sd = $sdRes.Descriptor
$trustee = ([wmiclass] 'Win32_Trustee').CreateInstance()
$trustee.Domain = $domain
$trustee.Name = $user
$fullControl = 31
$localLaunchActivate = 11
$ace = ([wmiclass] 'Win32_ACE').CreateInstance()
$ace.AccessMask = $localLaunchActivate
$ace.AceFlags = 0
$ace.AceType = 0
$ace.Trustee = $trustee
[System.Management.ManagementBaseObject[]] $newDACL = $sd.DACL + @($ace)
$sd.DACL = $newDACL
$app.SetLaunchSecurityDescriptor($sd)
```

**Set-ACl** will help you to do the *SetACL.exe* work

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but I am trying to get away from using `DcomPerm.exe`. Do you know how this is possible?

Comment: @methuselah: You can create an instance of  Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting

Comment: Can you show me how that would look like in my code?

Comment: @methuselah: I have edited the ans. I hope that could help you out

Comment: @methuselah: Pasted one sample for you

Comment: Thanks so after creating an instance of `Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting`, do I simply call `$dcomperm -da list`?

Comment: No you have to set the different parameters like one has been shown in the example. Follow the link also . for ACL you can directly use `Set-Acl` to get your work done.

Comment: The link is not there, can you please paste it?

Comment: Link is mentioned in the answer as reference link DCOM settings.

Comment: Thanks, also I am a bit confused about where to set the `permit level:r,l` in the code sample above, can you please show me?

Comment: I have to check the members in that case. Pls check this also [Link](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_dcomapplicationsetting/)