# DCOM machine level access and launch permissions via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dcom

Is it possible to set machine level "My Computer" access and launch permissions from PowerShell?

The equivalent of

```
DComPerm.exe -ma set name permit level:l,r
DComPerm.exe -ml set name permit level:l,r
```

I am looking for a solution using PowerShell v 3.0. The target servers are Windows Server 2008 R2 and 2012.

[image: My Computer Properties]

I have found a number of references for setting the DCOM application security settings. However I can't figure out how to set it at the machine or top level.

https://janbk.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/automating-dcom-acl-with-powershell/

[Alternative to using DcomPerm.exe and SetAcl.exe in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934149/alternative-to-using-dcomperm-exe-and-setacl-exe-in-powershell)

Comment: As i have suggested in the reference answer, have u looked into the Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting class..

Comment: Check this link too : [Link](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_dcomapplicationsetting/)

Comment: I am looking to set the permissions at the machine level. Win32_DCOMApplicationSettings seems to be at the application level only.

Answer (score 3):

We have been using WMI to set Launch Permissions. 
Refer: https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/using-powershell-to-modify-dcom-launch-activation-settings/

This stopped working after windows security patches rolled out (patch #: 4012212, 4012213, and 4012213)

We converted WIM powershell script to use CIM and that took care of setting launch permissions on DCOM objects & works with the security patches. Code is below for reference:

```
$ComponentName = "TestComponent" #--- change value as needed
$Username = "Username"           #--- change value as needed
$Domain = "Domain"               #--- change value as needed

# If you already have a CimSession that you used to get the security descriptor, you can leave this line out and use the existing one:
$CimSession = New-CimSession localhost

Grant-DComAccessToUser -ComponentName $ComponentName -Username $Username -Domain $Domain

# Cleanup
$CimSession | Remove-CimSession

function Grant-DComAccessToUser {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $ComponentName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Username,
        [string] $Domain
    )

    $DCom = Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * from Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting WHERE Description LIKE '$ComponentName%'"

    $GetDescriptor = Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $DCom -MethodName "GetLaunchSecurityDescriptor";

    $ExistingDacl = $GetDescriptor.Descriptor.DACL | Where {$_.Trustee.Name -eq $Username}

    if ($ExistingDacl)
    {
        $ExistingDacl.AccessMask = 11
    }
    else
    {
        $NewAce = New-DComAccessControlEntry -Domain $Domain -Username $Username
        $GetDescriptor.Descriptor.DACL += $NewAce
    }

    Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $DCom -MethodName "SetLaunchSecurityDescriptor" -Arguments @{Descriptor=$GetDescriptor.Descriptor};
}

function New-DComAccessControlEntry {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Username,
        [string] $Domain
    )

    # Create the Win32_Trustee instance
    $Trustee = New-Object ciminstance $CimSession.GetClass("root/cimv2", "Win32_Trustee")
    $Trustee.Name = $Username
    $Trustee.Domain = $Domain

    # Create the Win32_ACE instance
    $Ace = New-Object ciminstance $CimSession.GetClass("root/cimv2", "Win32_ACE")
    $Ace.AceType = [uint32] [System.Security.AccessControl.AceType]::AccessAllowed
    $Ace.AccessMask = 11
    $Ace.AceFlags = [uint32] [System.Security.AccessControl.AceFlags]::None
    $Ace.Trustee = $Trustee

    $Ace    
}
```

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something, both of those scripts use the "Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting" class. That class provides application level setting/access. I am looking to set the access at the "My Computer" or top level as shown in the original screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can change this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Get-DCOM-22da5b96. It works with application permissions using registry path "HKCR:\AppID\$ApplicationID" and registry keys "AccessPermission", "LaunchPermission".

You should use registry path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole" and registry keys "DefaultAccessPermission", "DefaultLaunchPermission", "MachineAccessRestriction", "MachineLaunchRestriction".

More info in "Configuring Remote DCOM" chapter: https://books.google.ru/books?id=rbpNppFdipkC&pg=PT211&lpg=PT211&dq=dcom+grant+local+launch+permission+powershell&source=bl&ots=5ZfeVca5NA&sig=9lMN_VeymG8cf73KT062QTsWWkc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikn73f6YLcAhVEDSwKHUftCwkQ6AEIfDAI#v=onepage&q&f=true